# Form Based Authentication with Tomcat

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, struts-1

I need to do form based authentication in Struts 1.3.10 + Tomcat

As per my understanding once login credentials are submitted, container would cross-check credentials with `tomcat-users.xml` and based on that forward to
success page or error page.

**login.jsp**

```xml
<form action="j_security_check" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="j_username"/>
    <input type="password" name="j_password"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

**web.xml**

```xml
<login-config>
    <form-login-check>
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-check>
</login-config>
```

**Doubt:**

if valid credentials are provided how server goes to success page ?
since in `login.jsp` acion I have given as `j_security_check` not as normal action which forward to success page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24241177/tomcat-7-realm-configuration-for-form-based-authentication

Answer (score 2):

The authentication is provided by the the server, so you should not be concerned how the server is doing it. The requested resource URL is stored somewhere by the server, then directs you to the login page, if your login is successful the requested resource is returned.

> When a user submits their name and password, the server determines if the user name and password are those of an authorized user and, if authorized, sends the requested web resource. If the topic of authentication is new to you, please refer to the section [Specifying an Authentication Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/bncbn/index.html).